# how to start apache http server into debuging mode for remote debugging?

Tags: http

I have uploaded applets on http server and wanted to enable remote debugging but din't finding anything in the documentation.
How to enable debug mode in apache http server?
Where to find listener port for remote debugging?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks,
Bhavesh Shah

Answer (score 0):

Some definitions

Applets runs in the client browser. 
Servlets run on the server.
*Tomcat* Apache is your servlet server.
Apache HTTP Server is nothing to do with your java servlets.

assuming that all of these things are true,

This link should help you out:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing